# Using the Activity Log Endpoint in the Facebook Marketing APIs

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-activity

I am interested in loading all the historical decisions made in ads accounts at the adset level (e.g. whenever a budget is updated). It looks like this is precisely the endpoint I should be using but the documentation looks incomplete.

Can anyone paste an example of how to invoke this endpoint correctly?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all adset level activities of an ad account use this endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_<AdAccountId>/activities?oid=<FirstAdSetId>&extra_oids=[<AllAdSetsIds>]&fields=object_id,object_name,event_type,translated_event_type,event_time,actor_id,actor_name,extra_data&since=<UnixTimestamp>&access_token=<AccessToken>
```

Follow this reference to customize your request:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/activities/